# unknown source log in logcat

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am using HUAWEI c8812 for debuging.
There are quite a lot logs from unknown source showing by logcat besides my own log. 
Unknown source logs are so many(like following) and outputed all the time, so that my own logs are flushed out and disapper, even with filter.

```
12-04 13:46:09.159: E/LocSvc_utils_q(298): D/msg_q_rcv: Waiting on message
12-04 13:46:09.159: E/LocSvc_utils_q(298): D/msg_q_snd: Finished Sending message with handle = 0x00756AF0
12-04 13:46:09.159: E/LocSvc_adapter(298): D/loc_eng_report_nmea: $RMC
12-04 13:46:09.159: E/LocSvc_adapter(298): V/Exiting int32 loc_event_cb(void*, rpc_loc_client_handle_type, rpc_loc_event_mask_type, const rpc_loc_event_payload_u_type*) line 73 0
12-04 13:46:09.159: E/LocSvc_api_rpc_glue(298): V/cb_func=0x4e27c785
12-04 13:46:09.159: E/LocSvc_api_rpc_glue(298): V/proc: 1  prog: 3100008c  vers: 50001
12-04 13:46:09.159: E/LocSvc_api_rpc_glue(298): V/Callback received: 4 (cb_id=0x12a0000 handle=0 ret_ptr=1280888372)
```

how to disable it output these unknown logs ?

Comment: And your question about this is?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to see just your log messages?  DDMS/Logcat allows you to set a filter on the output.  You can filter by log tag, message content, severity.

Comment: Maybe you are seeing system logs

Comment: no, as I said unkonwn source log are too many and coming out all the time, my own log are flush out and disappear.

Comment: are you using Eclipse?

Comment: yes, I am using Eclipse.

Comment: Appart from filtering the messages, Does anyone knows what's the cause of this dump of error and how to deal with GPS service to not fire them.

I'm Using Galaxy Note 3 and it throws that errors, but on my Nexus five, it doesn't.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out your logs through your app/package name keywords and your logs will appear in logcat.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks,  filter does not work 'cause unkown source logs are too many and outputed all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the lines that are displayed in Logcat, the default is around 1500 lines and these lines are managed as a queue buffer. On my Eclipse I've setup to keep 1.500.000 lines. From Eclipse top menus: `Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Logcat` and there set in `Maximum number of logcat messages to buffer` the number of Logcat lines to keep. Check below image:

[image]

Also you need to make sure you have enough RAMs since Eclipse will start using a lot of memory. On a workstation with 8GB, I have allocated 4GB for Eclipse by setting these properties in `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx4096m
```